# Case Milestone fields are not visible in lightning

Tags: case, lightning-experience, servicecloud, case-object, casemilestone

As per Salesforce [Winter ’17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/cases_fields.htm) most of the Case Mile Stone fields are Available in both: Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience. But I am not able to see Milestone Status Icon & Timeline fields in Lightning. Both fields are visible in the Classic view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_statuses.htm&type=0), the status icons you see differ based on where the milestone appears and whether you’re in Salesforce Classic or Lightning Experience.

[image]